# Tauberian Theorem for 1-parameter groups of operators

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

The [Wiener Tauberian Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TauberianTheorem.html) gives condition on an $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that the "induced 1-parameter family" $\{T_b(f)\}_{b\in \mathbb{R}}$ has a dense span in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$; where $T_b$ is the Group of transation operators on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $f\mapsto T_b(\mathbb{R})$.

---

Are there other "similar results" stating that:  Given a group (under composition) $(T_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ of (continuous linear) operators on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then:
$$
\mbox{If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies ___ then $\overline{\operatorname{span}(\{T_t(f)\}_{t\in\mathbb{R}}}=L^1(\mathbb{R})$.}
$$

---

**Note:** I would be interested (though less so) in results where either:

- $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is replaced by $C(\mathbb{R})$ with the [compact-convergence topology.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence)
- $(T_t)_{t}$ forms a semi-group,
- If $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by a locally-compact topological group  $G$ and the Lebesgue measure by the [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) on $G$

**Related Post:** [Here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394926/cyclic-vectors-for-the-translation-operator?noredirect=1#comment1010626_394926)

---

**(What I'm not looking for):**  I just note that conditions on $f$ which I would not be interested in, are those relating to [hyper/super-cyclicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercyclic_operator).  This is because, such conditions need $f$ to be "infinitely complicated" (see [this paper](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Eprims/pdf/43-2/43-2-17.pdf)) while I'm looking for "tractable/simple $f$" (as in Wiener's case).

Comment: OK, I convert my answer to an "insightful comment" (first time I go that way :). For the combinatorial side of one-parameter deformations, you can have a look [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401126). 
For the question of existence of a cyclic vector, there is a bunch of examples in § 4.2 for which you can test the density of the orbits.  
Do not hesitate to interact (I can provide missing proofs and details on request, of course).

Comment: Thanks Gérard, I really do appreciate the comment and I currently looking through your paper.  I do feel abit silly, but I don't quite see where density in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ comes in.  (P.s.: Let me just briefly mention that I didn't downvote your earlier answer...so no hard feelings :) )

Comment: OK, I understand. The paper does not offer already elaborated statement about density, but, rather, there are a lot of situations and, I think, a setting to explore some type of one-parameter groups (acting on holomorphic or continuous functions). So, ok, do not loose time if it does not fit directly your research thread.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Still thanks a lot, I'll continue reading it and I'll let you know if I have any questions.  Thanks again :)

Comment: In the direction of replacing $\mathbf{R}$ by other locally compact groups, I believe that Wiener's Tauberian theorem works perfectly well for locally compact abelian groups. For non abelian groups, I do not know what is the current state of knowledge. It was apparently open in 1976 whether this holds for groups with polynomial growth, see https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0338.43005. See also Yulia Kuznetsova's answer here for other examples and references: https://mathoverflow.net/q/84943

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle Thanks I'm looking in to these links.  Still, I'm most interested in the the main question; i.e.: which groups we have a sufficient condition on $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that: $\overline{span(T_t)(f)}=L^1(\mathbb{R})$